# Netty Http Connection Provider maxLifeTime settings

Tags: java, reactor-netty

According to the documentation [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_connection_pool) for `maxLifeTime` the channel is `Eligible to be closed` after the defined life time. Is there any chance that a connection will be used after the `maxLifeTime` is elapsed but the connection is not closed yet ?

For ex., in the code below,

```
ConnectionProvider.builder("custom")
                                  .maxConnections(50)
                                  .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(20))           
                                  .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofSeconds(60))           
                                  .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60)) 
                                  .evictInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(120))    
                                  .build();
```

Is there any chance for a connection be reused after 60 seconds of `maxLifeTime` and chances of it getting closed in the middle of a process assuming the `evictInBackground` process kicks in after 120 seconds ?

I am trying to solve a connection reset issue and would like to understand how netty connection provider settings work ?

Answer (score 0):

`maxLifeTime` is checked on:

- `connection release` to the connection pool - which means the response has already been delivered
- or before `connection acquire` from the connection pool
- or on `background eviction` - background eviction is made only for the idle connections in the connection pool i.e. these are connections that do not process requests at the moment